# Analyze the convergence behavior of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{2^{2k}}-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{3^{2k+1}}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Analyze the convergence behavior of the following series: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{2^{2k}}-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{3^{2k+1}}.$$

I came across this problem as I was preparing for an exam.  It is supposed to be an easy one but I am not sure which test to apply.

Comment: Hint: determine for which values of $x$ the general term of the series converges to zero. Or use the criterion based on the limsup of the $n$th root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2k}}{2^{2k}}-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{3^{2k+1}}\right)$$ is intended. You can avoid worrying about uniform convergence by using the ratio test. Calling the $k$-th term $a_k$, and letting $u=x/2$, we have

$$a_k=\left(\frac{x}2\right)^{2k}-\left(\frac{x}3\right)^{2k+1}=u^{2k}-\left(\frac23\right)^{2k+1}u^{2k+1}=u^{2k}\left(1-\left(\frac23\right)^{2k+1}u\right)\;,$$

so

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty}u^2\left|\frac{1-(2/3)^{2k+3}u}{1-(2/3)^{2k+1}u}\right|=u^2\;.$$

Clearly you need $u^2<1$, or $|x|<2$, and it’s not hard to check that you don’t get convergence at either endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Break it in two using the - sign.  Then examine the pieces using the root or ratio test.  More simply, realize that both series are geometric, which converges when the common ration is less than 1 in absolute value.

Comment: but to break it don't we need to know that the series converges uniformly?

Comment: It has to converge absolutely.  Power series converge absolutely in the interior of their intervals of convergence.  Find the intervals of convergence; one fits inside the other.  Then you can check at the smaller interval's endpoints separately.  This will tell all.